# Trying to show all files of sd-card on Toast

Tags: android

I am trying to show all the files of all folder of sd-card on a toast.but it is only showing the list of folders not the subfolder/files of all folders.

```css
File root=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
  getFilesRecursive(root);
  }

 private void getFilesRecursive(File dir) 
 {
  if (dir.exists()) 
  {
  File[] files=dir.listFiles();
  //Toast.makeText(Viruslist.this, "Nos:"+files.length, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  
  for (int i = 0; i <files.length; i++) 
   {
   File file=files[i];
   if (file.isDirectory()) 
    {
      getFilesRecursive(file);
    } 
   else 
    {
    name=file.getName();
    Toast.makeText(Viruslist.this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
   file=null;
   }
  
  }
  else
  {
   Toast.makeText(Viruslist.this, "No", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
  
  
 }

}
```

Comment: It will not show.. If you want track the subfolders or file you need to travel recursively through the subfolders as well.

Comment: how? some hint please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void someMethod()
{
traverse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
}      

 public void traverse (File dir) {
        if (dir.exists()) {
            File[] files = dir.listFiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
                File file = files[i];
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    traverse(file);
                } else {

                    //print toast 
                }
            }
          files = null;
        }
    }
```

this identifies the files inside the each directory .. Try this.. try nullifying objects as soon as its usage is done. try doing this in a background thread .. cause it might take time

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77094/discussion-on-answer-by-preethi-rao-trying-to-show-all-files-of-sd-card-on-toast).